# APPCRASH after ca. 40 sec

Tags: c++, windows-7, crash-reports

I have a multithreading server application which runs fine for the first ca. 40 seconds (in this time the application is pretty much only waiting for incoming packets). After these 40 seconds it suddenly crashes although nothing changed, no clients connected, no data got send etc.

The crash-report I receive from windows is this:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: myapplicationname.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    508d2a0b
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_58df
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdb3b
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 000cdcbb
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1031
  Additional Information 1: 58df
  Additional Information 2: 58df710f17985997dec7b600103e4fd6
  Additional Information 3: bc2b
  Additional Information 4: bc2b581ed6e84cb4442c19134e8081d3
```

I checked for possible buffer overflows, memory leaks but that's not the case (at least I didn't notice any).

Apart from that, what confused me even more is that, if I compile it and run it in Visual Studio (Local Windows Debugger) this error doesn't happen, no crash, everything is working as it's supposed to. I don't know where to start in order to fix this since I've never had such a problem.

I know it is difficult to diagnose something without having the code but there is just too much code and I can't limit it since I don't know what this error even means and what it is related to. I'm just hoping someone has encountered something similar or knows what this error means. So far I only found how to fix similar problems for other programs (re-install the application was the answer).

**Wild guess:**
I have a poll loop which is putting a lot of stress on one of my threads since I didn't get to the point to implement the whole code. Is it possible that DEP is getting invoked and stops my application in order to protect one of my cpus? -Added a Sleep but didn't change anything.

Comment: Does it crash if you compile a release build without optimisations? It could be that a certain optimisation causes the error to happen.

Comment: Disabled optimization (/Od) but still got the same problem.

Comment: `I know it is difficult to diagnose something without having the code but there is just too much code and I can't limit it since I don't know what this error even means and what it is related to.` You have to narrow it down! Process of elimination. Yes it's painstaking and time-consuming, but, well, welcome to software development.

Comment: "pretty much only waiting for incoming packets" and " I have a poll loop which is putting a lot of stress on one of my threads" are mutually exclusive. The StackHash location hint is telling you Windows cannot identify the module where the fault happened. The exception (though possibly bogus) indicates heap corruption. At least *some* hint of what the "pretty much only waiting for incoming packets" (which is **NOT** only waiting for packets) code does may help determine why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception Code:   c0000374

You'll find these exception codes documented in the ntstatus.h SDK header file:

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION
//
// MessageText:
//
// A heap has been corrupted.
//
#define STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION           ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000374L)
```

Heap corruption is of course a very common C++ programming hazard.  Use the debug allocator available in crtdbg.h if you cannot locate the bug.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me to narrow it down. I wish things like this would be mentioned in my books.

Comment: Yes, books never talk about this.  It is learned in the School of Hard Knocks ;)